When I choose hardware on a shopping website, how do I choose gold color?
I can't tell the difference between "GOLD" and "brushed brass" and I'm worried that the description won't match the actual product.
For example, in the following three pictures: which one is "GOLD" and which one is "brushed brass"?




Look for the description.  If it doesn't say Gold then skip it or ask the supplier if it is Gold.
In addition to the colour, the finish makes a huge difference in appearance - gloss, satin, brushed etc.
However, different supplier's finishes will be different.  If you are going to be fussy about the finish, or if you want the colour to match the items already sourced from elsewhere then visit a physical store.

Look at specifications.   If it is labeled "gold colored" then it is gold.   If it is brass it will say that.    When ordering things and you are unsure of color then send the company an email/chat to confirm.    Welcome to my world of buying these days - the more choices the more goes wrong.
